# Dates comparison in Java

Tags: java, jsp, date

I'm trying to compare two dates with the current date. It seems not to work when I try to know if a date is the same as the current date. Here's what I do in my code :

```
//BeginDate is set earlier

Date myDate= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(BeginDate);
Date now = new Date();

    System.out.println("Now : " + now);
    System.out.println("myDate : " + myDate);
    System.out.println("equals : " + myDate.equals(now));
    System.out.println(myDate.compareTo(now));
```

And I get this in the console :

```
Now : Thu Dec 29 00:28:45 CET 2011
myDate : Thu Dec 29 00:00:00 CET 2011
equals : false
-1
```

The first comparison should return true and the second "0" right ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: 1) Where is `begin` coming from? 2) The first `equals` will return false because the dates are not the same.  You need to `SimpleDateFormat` the `now` date as well.

Comment: what is the result of BeginDate that you set before?

Comment: BeginDate is a String set as "29/11/2011"

Comment: just use `SimpleDateFormat("dd")` format to compare the days

Comment: Yeah but I want to compare the entire date, not just the day in month.

Comment: you said the day, that's why I suggested this. In that case you can follow to the Wilmer's suggestion. Convert the dates into strings and then compare them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison is failing because you need to format now so that both dates have the same format and thus may be compared.

Or, if you prefer, you can convert dates into strings and perform the comparison:

```
    String beginDate = "28/12/2011";
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String nowStr = df.format(new Date());
    System.out.println("equals : " + beginDate.equals(nowStr));
```

Comment: I used your code to get a `String` and put in a `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(nowStr)`, so I can compare with my other dates, because they are set the same way (with juste dd/mm/yyy). Thanks !

Comment: If you want `compareTo` to give the right answers, you'll need to use a format that specifies the year first, then the month, then the date.

Answer (score 5):

Comparing dates with either equals() or compareTo() compares the times (hours, minutes, seconds, millis) as well as the dates.  Your test is failing because `myDate` is midnight today, whereas `now` is a little later than that.

Comment: Okay, good to know ^^ Any suggestions on how to compare just the dates (the days) ?

Comment: I don't know of a "nice" way of doing that.  What I usually do is make a Calendar object out of each of the dates that I want to compare, then set the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to zero in each Calendar, then compare the Calendars.  Have a look at the Javadoc for Calendar, and post again if you can't figure it out.  If anyone knows a simpler way of doing this, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @ShiniFox, Joda time is a calendrical library for Java that makes these things easier.  It has [`LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) which is just a day and separate from a `DateTime`.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard good things about Joda time.  I've been meaning to get round to learning it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying the milliseconds when creating the dates? If you are, don't. So when creating the dates earlier, only specify the Day, Hour etc, not seconds/milliseconds.

And, change the SimpleDateFormat respectively. That "should" work.

Answer (score 0):

*Date* object in Java is nothing but a number that represents milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. It doesn't have any attribute called day, date, month, year etc. That's because date, month, year varies based on the type of calendar and timezone. These attributes belong to *Calendar* instance.

So, if you have 2 *Date* objects and you want to compare day of month, month and year then you should create corresponding *Calendar* instance and compare them separately.

```
// Parse begin date
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date beginDate = dateFormat.parse(beginDateAsString);
// Create calendar instances
Calendar beginDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
beginDateCalendar.setTime(beginDate);
Calendar todayCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
// Check Equals
boolean dayEquals = todayCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == beginDateCalendar
        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
boolean monthEquals = todayCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == beginDateCalendar
        .get(Calendar.MONTH);
boolean yearEquals = todayCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == beginDateCalendar
        .get(Calendar.YEAR);
// Print Equals
System.out.println(dayEquals && monthEquals && yearEquals);
```

Above code is cumbersome for the current problem but explains how date operations must be done in JAVA.

If you just want to solve the equals problem you have mentioned then the code below will suffice:

```
String todayAsString = (new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")).format(new Date());
System.out.println(beginDateAsString.equals(todayAsString));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to be dealing with dates between the years 1900 and 2100, there is a simple calculation which will give you the number of days since 1900:

```
public static int daysSince1900(Date date) {
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.setTime(date);

    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900;
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int days = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    if (month < 3) {
        month += 12;
        year--;
    }
    int yearDays = (int) (year * 365.25);
    int monthDays = (int) ((month + 1) * 30.61);

    return (yearDays + monthDays + days - 63);
}
```

Thus, Date (only) comparison can be achieved by checking if the number of days since 1900 of the 2 dates are equal.

**NOTE:** The above method should have code added to check if the dates are outside the valid range (1/1/1900 - 31/12/2099) and throw an IllegalArgumentException.

And don't ask me where this calculation came from because we've used it since the early '90s.